# Get Slide previews (thumbnails) in a PowerPoint Add-In (Web)

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I'm creating a PowerPoint Add-In and wrestling with the JavaScript API.

I'm currently trying to show the list of slides (much like the left panel in powerpoint). I also want to highlight the slide that is currently worked on.

I got the index of the currently selected slide by:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.SlideRange,
    function (result) {
        result.value.slides[0].index; // selected slide
    }
);
```

But I'm not able to enumerate all slides much yet get the image data of one.

In the old VSTO world I was able to iterate through slides with:

```
foreach (var slide in MyAdmin.ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides)
```

And get slide image data with:

```
slide.Export(ImageName, "jpg",128,72);
```

and read it back from disk (although creating an image on the disk just for this seems wasteful).

Is there an equivalent of this in the office.js world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the JavaScript API does not have a method for getting the image of a slide. But it is a great idea! Please go to [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and suggest this enhancement. You might also want to vote up [this suggestion](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5934397-allow-powerpoint-to-send-unique-slides-as-an-image).

Comment: The JavaScript API is really disappointing. I have yet to see any useful plugin in it that does anything apart from trivial tasks, only "Search on Wikipedia" style plugins.