# Get preview / thumbnail / image of individual slides in PowerPoint using OfficeJS and Office Add-Ins (Web)

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

We need to obtain image previews or thumbnails of each slide in an Office Add-In. We are currently developing a functionality using Office Add-Ins (PowerPoint), where users can open a PowerPoint presentation (hosted remotely) and click on the presentation to view all slides (with preview images) in the right panel of the Office Add-In. They should also be able to select a slide and insert it. We have searched through the Office Add-Ins documentation, but we could not find any method that can be used to generate thumbnail of the slides. We would greatly appreciate any assistance or alternative solutions to achieve this in Office Add-Ins.

Looked into Microsoft office add-ins documentation

Comment: I love this concept! Good luck :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Slide previews (thumbnails) in a PowerPoint Add-In (Web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190482/get-slide-previews-thumbnails-in-a-powerpoint-add-in-web)

Comment: Sorry no. This thread is 7 years old and don't have answers which I can use.

Comment: That is an automated comment because I flagged this as a duplicate. You really should be bringing attention to the existing question, not posting a duplicate. I understand tho, because you have no "rep" you can't bounty the Q which is how I'd bring it back from the "dead".